# HTML: Multiple submit buttons in a form, each leading to a different python script?

Tags: html

How can I do this? Doesn't a form only have one action? What if I have 3 different buttons at the end of a form and each one invokes a different script? Much appreciated.

Comment: thanks to whoever downvoted and didn't even write anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is possible, but not in pure html. You need javascript for that, because a html forms action is defined in the form tag, which accepts only a single action.

Using javascript however you can register differrent handlers for the click events of different submit buttons, thus send the forms data to different locations.

Comment: So to do what I want with python, I could just have a main program that calls one of the three sub-programs based on the form's 'submit button' name?

Comment: Sorry, can't follow there. You were talking about html markup before. I assumed you were using that inside a web browser. I don't see the connection to python and "subprograms" here.

Comment: well regardless of the program im using, the post will still send the name of the button which it was submitted by. i can use that to figure out which program is meant to be run. im not sure what you dont get?

Comment: That is indeed true, you could evaluate that and run through different behavior on the server side like this.